# C++ how to handle file with multiple data types?

Tags: c++, input, file-io, output

I have an input txt file which contains information like this:

```
    4
    Eric Nandos
    3
    15.00 45.00 36.81 64.55 50.50
    51.52 36.40 25.15 35.45 24.55
    41.55 44.55 36.35 55.50 40.55
    Steven Abraham
    2
    40.45 20.35 40.46 30.35 55.50
    18.25 18.00 20.00 30.00 60.65
    Richard Mccullen
    2
    40.45 50.55 20.45 30.30 20.25
    30.00 20.00 40.00 60.60 45.45
    Stacey Vaughn
    3
    45.00 25.00 15.00 30.30 25.20
    20.20 60.65 55.55 50.50 50.40
    30.30 60.55 20.25 20.00 40.00
```

With getline(file, string) I am able to store this data into a string variable and then output it.
The problem is, I need to store the different data types into different variables in order to do certain operations with them (ex: I need to average the decimal values, add the different int values, store some data into a vector, etc). I've tried different loops to parse through the file, but I've been getting an error every time. Any advice on how to separate the different data here so I can store them accordingly? I'm still new to C++ so I don't have much experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line specifies the number of records in the file, where each individual record then consists of:

- 1 line for a person's name
- 1 line specifying the number of following lines
- N number of lines of floating-point numbers

You can read such data like this:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

...

int numRecords, numLines;
std::string name, line;
double value;

std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    // error handling...
}

if (!(file >> numRecords)) {
    // error handling ...
}

file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; ++i)
{
    if (!std::getline(file, name)) {
        // error handling...
    }

    // use name as needed...

    if (!(file >> numLines)) {
        // error handling...
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numLines; ++j)
    {
        if (!std::getline(file, line)) {
            // error handling...
        }

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> value) {
            // use value as needed...
        }
        if (iss.fail()) {
            // error handling...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `std::ifstream`[<sup>**0**</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)'s from `<fstream>`[<sup>**1**</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).
It works like exactly like `std::cin`[<sup>**2**</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), except with a file.
[Example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt#Example)
Here's a practical implementation: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xfjox3e1o)